# while loop is not breaking out in python

Tags: python, while-loop, nested

I am trying to built number guessing game. I created a `game()` function that first lets you pick difficulty level and according to the level loops through in that amount and asks for users to guess. My problem here is getting out of the loop. I created a boolean named `is_continue`, set it to `True`, and wanted to use it whenever it needs to be broken out of the loop (which are when you guessed the right number and when you want to end the game), but not only is it not breaking out of the loop but also it keeps re-looping even though the range amount is completed.

```
from random import randint
from replit import clear

value = randint(1, 100)

def compare(guess, value):
  if guess > value:
    print("Too high.")
  elif guess < value:
    print("Too low.")  
  else:
    print(f"You got it! The answer was {value}")

def game(): 
  print("Welcome to the number guessing game.")
  print("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100.")
  difficulty_level = input("Choose a difficulty. Type 'easy' or 'hard'.")
  is_continue = False
  while not is_continue:
    if difficulty_level == "easy":
      e_attempt = 10
      for x in range (10):
        print (f"You have {e_attempt} attempts.")
        e_attempt -= 1
        guess = int(input("Guess a number?"))
        compare(guess, value)
        if guess == value: 
          is_continue = True
        if x == 9:
          print("You've run out of guess. You lose.")
          if input("Type 'c' to continue and 'e' to end.") == "c":
            clear()
            game()
          else:
            # I put print function to check weather else statement is working.
            print("else statement has been read.")
            is_continue = True
            
    elif difficulty_level == "hard":
      h_attempt = 5
      for x in range (5):
        print (f"You have {h_attempt} attempts.")
        h_attempt -= 1
        guess = int(input("Guess a number?"))
        compare(guess, value)
        if guess == value:
          is_continue = True
        if x == 4:         
          print("You've run out of guess. You lose.")
          if input("Type 'c' to continue and 'e' to end.") == "c":
            clear()
            game()
          else:
            clear()
  clear()
       
game()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code inside the `game` function says `game()`, exactly what do you expect that to mean - what do you think will happen, in detail, when that code runs?

Comment: Try adding `is_continue = True` in else part of `if input("Type 'c' to continue and 'e' to end.") == "c":` statement

Comment: Setting `is_continue = True` does not stop the loop **immediately**.  The current loop iteration will keep executing.  If you want the loop to stop **immediately**, use `break`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you asign value `True` to `is_continue` variable it will not break out of your while loop. You can type `break` to break out of for loop that is currenty running and on next iteration of while loop it will not execute because the value of `is_continue` variable is set to `True`.

Code example:

```
while not is_continue:
    if difficulty_level == "easy":
      e_attempt = 10
      for x in range (10):
        print (f"You have {e_attempt} attempts.")
        e_attempt -= 1
        guess = int(input("Guess a number?"))
        compare(guess, value)
        if guess == value: 
          is_continue = True
          break  # this was added
```

Keep in mind that asigning a value to variables in while loop is not a good thing in this example. The variable `difficulty_level` will never change throughout your code. After your for loop ends, it will actually start again. `break` is a great way to break out of current loop you are into, especially when using nested loops.

I hope my answer helps and good luck coding!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be due to how you're using the `is_continue` boolean variable. You change `is_continue` to `True` in your code when the player guesses the correct number, but you also set it to `True` when the player decides to continue playing after the guesses run out. This can allow the cycle to continue even after the player has exhausted his or her tries.

To address this issue, use a `break` statement to stop the loop immediately when the player guesses the correct number or decides to end the game.

```
def game():
    print("Welcome to the number guessing game.")
    print("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100.")
    difficulty_level = input("Choose a difficulty. Type 'easy' or 'hard'.")
    is_continue = True  # Set is_continue to True initially
    while is_continue:  # Use while loop with is_continue as the condition
        if difficulty_level == "easy":
            e_attempt = 10
            for x in range(10):
                print(f"You have {e_attempt} attempts.")
                e_attempt -= 1
                guess = int(input("Guess a number?"))
                compare(guess, value)
                if guess == value:
                    print("You win!")
                    is_continue = False  # Set is_continue to False to exit the loop
                    break  # Exit the loop immediately
                if x == 9:
                    print("You've run out of guesses. You lose.")
                    if input("Type 'c' to continue and 'e' to end.") == "c":
                        clear()
                        game()
                    else:
                        is_continue = False  # Set is_continue to False to exit the loop
                        break  # Exit the loop immediately

        elif difficulty_level == "hard":
            h_attempt = 5
            for x in range(5):
                print(f"You have {h_attempt} attempts.")
                h_attempt -= 1
                guess = int(input("Guess a number?"))
                compare(guess, value)
                if guess == value:
                    print("You win!")
                    is_continue = False  # Set is_continue to False to exit the loop
                    break  # Exit the loop immediately
                if x == 4:
                    print("You've run out of guesses. You lose.")
                    if input("Type 'c' to continue and 'e' to end.") == "c":
                        clear()
                        game()
                    else:
                        is_continue = False  # Set is_continue to False to exit the loop
                        break  # Exit the loop immediately

    clear()

game()
```

Also, when the player decides to end the game by typing 'e', it's important to set `is_continue` to `False` so that the loop is exited and the game ends.